# AC clutch plate on and off

Tags: ac, clutch, compressor, refrigerant, air-compressor

My ac was not working so I installed a new ac pulley, clutch plate, and coil. Now it seems to be working fine again. I notice, however, that the clutch plate engages and disengages fairly regularly (may be every minute).

I have read somewhere that once the pressure in the ac system drops to a certain level the clutch plate will kick in (or the opposite?) to bring the pressure in line again. So perhaps the clutch plate is not meant to stay engaged constantly and that occasional disengaging is normal. Is this correct? And, if yes, how frequent should this engaging/disengaging be for it to be normal?

Thank you.

Comment: This is normal operation, frequency depends on ambient temperature and rpm of engine.

Answer (score 0):

The frequency that it engages/disengages depends on outside temperature, how much the car is moving or sitting still, and other things specific to the vehicle. It is often normal operation for the clutch to engage/disengage fairly frequently, say 2 or 3 times a minute on a hot day.